# How to enable POS payment on my C# windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms, payment-gateway, payment-processing

**How the data on card is read to POS application?**

I have been told some of the information such as card no and the holder's name is displayed on to the screen of the supervisor's terminal. In order to send the card information to the POS supervisor app, `Keypress()` event SHOULD BE used.

How do i send card information from POS card swipe machine to POS app? because just by installing drivers and configuring payment gateways would not send data to pos app. what i must do to make that `keypress()` event execute? im sure the developer has to write code to get that string data from the POS card swipe machine. Would you be generous enough to go through the process and show some sample code (sample code in online or some code you would like to share) on how to do it? because there is no way from out of no where the `Keypress()` event executes on a card swipe?

Comment: First, please ask one question per question on this site. Second, do you seriously expect someone to do _all_ of your research for you?

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for the comment, since both questions are related to each other i thought it would be meaningful to put them in one

Comment: Meaningful or not, please don't do that.

Comment: okay then lesson learned! : ) let me put them in two now

Comment: well i have to wait another 90 minutes to post the second part

Comment: If it's a keyboard wedge type card-reader, then you don't have to do anything. The card-swipe will trigger `keypress` events - because it appears as a keyboard to the computer.

Comment: okay finaly i have posted my second part fter 90minutes [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066744/how-to-install-pos-card-reader-for-my-c-sharp-windows-app[/link]

Comment: @Blorgbeard its a separate unit : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this sounds like a PCI DSS nightmare. Displaying card information on screen is a definite problem, and the following code leaves you vulnerable to keylogging and memory parsing. That said...

If you're expected to use a `KeyPress` event for this, I assume you're receiving the track info from a keyboard wedge MSR, which is pretty simple - it just spits out the track info in plain text. You could use a `KeyPress` event to handle each character entered, and then send the string on the track end sentinel (typically `?`):

Let's assume for simplicity's sake that you're swiping into a WinForms `TextBox`:

In your Form Designer select your text box, go to Events and add a KeyPress handler, or alternatively in your Form's `InitializeComponent()` method, attach it manually:

```
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyPress);
```

Then define your KeyPress event in the Form's code-behind:

```
private StringBuilder trackInfo;
private bool track1Complete = false;

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar != '?' && !track1Complete)
    {
        trackInfo.Append(e.KeyChar);
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '?' && !track1Complete)
    {
        trackInfo.Append(e.KeyChar);
        trackInfo.AppendLine();
        track1Complete = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar != '?' && track1Complete)
    {
        trackInfo.Append(e.KeyChar);
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '?' && track1Complete)
    {
        trackInfo.Append(e.KeyChar);
        trackInfo.AppendLine();
        sendTrackInfo();
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is parsing the `KeyChar` on each `KeyPress` event argument triggered by the swipe. `?` is the typical end sentinel for a single track, and there are two tracks that are considered necessary for processing a card (see here for more on the format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#Financial_cards) - so we consider the card info completed at the end of the second track.

You're going to need to define the `sendTrackInfo()` method referenced above to format (remove sentinels, separate, etc) and send the track data you've collected in `trackInfo.ToString()` to your supervisor app, possibly in XML or as a stream.

Comment: The verifone is a standalone unit. It's going to encrypt track data on swipe and use its connection to send that data out to the processor. I haven't looked at verifone specifically, but most processors have a standard XML format containing encrypted and unencrypted info, transferred over SSL. I don't think you can intercept data from your device, by design.

Comment: the reason i have mentioned about verifone i have some stored using massive size (size of a standard book) POS units and when swipe the card i have seen my card information shown up at the POS application. the units similar to the ones in this link [link]http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Credit_card_terminal.jpg